# Round any odd values to even values within specific columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to round any odd values to *the next* even values in columns in Python (except the number 1)

**Data**

```
site    a    b   c
bali    5    3   1
mali    7    19  1
```

**Desired**

```
site    a    b   c
bali    6    4   1
mali    8    20  1
```

**Doing**

setting this up, but I am stuck on how to point to the specific columns

```
if($num % 2 == 1)
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set 'site' column as the index, using `DataFrame.set_index` so that the DataFrame only contains numeric columns. This can be generalised if you contain more non-numeric columns besides 'site'. Then, mask the numbers (`nums`) that are odd (`nums % 2`) and different from 1 (`nums != 1`), and add 1 to them, leaving the remaining unchanged. This can be done using [`DataFrame.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html). Finally, reset the index of the DataFrames so that 'site' is a column again.

```
# get all the non-numeric columns, like 'site', in the case you have multiple ones 
str_cols = df.select_dtypes(exclude='number').columns.tolist()

df = (
    df.set_index(str_cols)    # set the non-numeric column(s) as index 
      .mask(lambda nums: (nums % 2 == 1) & (nums != 1),  # add 1 to every odd number !=1 
            lambda nums: nums + 1)                  # and leave the remaining unchanched 
      .reset_index()  # restore the non-numeric column(s) 
)

>>> df

   site  a   b  c
0  bali  6   4  1
1  mali  8  20  1
```

---

Actually, setting and resetting the index can be avoided. Here is a simpler version of the above solution

```
# get all the numeric columns 
num_cols = df.select_dtypes(include='number').columns.tolist()

# update only the numeric columns with the same logic 
df[num_cols] = df[num_cols].mask(lambda nums: (nums % 2 == 1) & (nums != 1),
                                 lambda nums: nums + 1)
```

Comment: oh  I thought it was working but I get an error TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting - for some reason the string columns I think are having an issue

Comment: @Lynn If you have more than one string column, besides 'site', you have to add them to `set_index`, i.e.  `set_index(['site', 'str_col1', 'str_col2', ...])`

Comment: @Lynn I updated the answer to take that into account. Tell me if it works.

Comment: ok I got this error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'float' and 'bool' - I think I have to do some conversions. I will troubleshoot, I think what you provide is a good start thank you

Comment: @Lynn Try `(nums % 2 == 1) ` instead of just `nums % 2`. I guess the error comes from that line.

Comment: @Lynn I updated the answer with a simpler solution! Check if it works.

Answer (score 2):

In your case do

```
df.update(df.select_dtypes(np.number).applymap(lambda x : 1 if x==1 else x//2*2))
   a   b  c
0  4   2  1
1  6  18  1
```

Comment: Hi @BENY for some reason it is rounding my value of 5 to 4... I wish to round up. Perhaps I have to add the .ceil?

Comment: @Lynn yes and then do above

Comment: ok could I do: df.update(df.select_dtypes(np.number).applymap(lambda x : 1 if x==1 else x//2*2)).apply(np.ceil))  ? @BENY

Comment: @Lynn `df.update(df.select_dtypes(np.number).apply(np.ceil).applymap(lambda x : 1 if x==1 else x//2*2)))`

Comment: ok thankyou- for some reason, the '5' values rounds down to 4 - I am troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

use simple numpy to exclude 1

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([
    [5, 3, 1],
    [7, 19,1]
])

data = data + (data%2 * np.where(data==1, 0, 1))

print(data)

# array([[ 6,  4,  1],
#        [ 8, 20,  1]])
```

Comment: Thank you @Sai Li it is saying TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting -perhaps due to my column names